# Vue not updating global state

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some problems with updating the global state. I'm trying to update that state by listening WebSocket, but it's not updating as expected.
Here is how did I define the global state.

```
state: {
        userData: null
},
getters: {
  userData: state => {
        return state.userData
},
mutations: {
   GET_USER({payload}) {
  commit('GET_USER', payload)
},
```

And I'm updating it in App.vue like so:

```
mounted() {
        window.Echo.channel("user." + this.userData.id).listen(".user-updated", (user) => {
              this.$store.commit('GET_USER', JSON.stringify(user.user))
        });
```

Ofcourse I'm closing that websocket. I tried with localStorage, which I think is not a bad idea, but still I'm doing it with global state, and with localstorage would look like:

```
      localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user.user))
```

So when I want to show that data in some component, for example, Home.vue, the Only way that I can see what is happening, is by defining `{{ this.$store.getters.userData }}` in the template of that file, but If I try to define it in scripts data, like so:

```
     data() {
             return {
                 data: this.$store.getters.userData,
             }
        },
```

It's not updating real time, but only if I go to another page and return here, or update the component.
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had success by accessing the state. As far as I understand it it should be reactive as well `this.$store.state.userData` and reflect the current state of the store just as well.

Keep in mind accessing object properties might not be reactive the way you think they are: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects
So you probably want to define a getter where you access the user's name, credentials, whatever userData holds.

The more explicit approach is defining every property of the userData object in the store and write a mutation for every property individually (loops are possible to do that at once, of course, but you'll have to create the mutators still).

```js
{
  state: {
    userData: {
      id: null,
      name: '',
      email: '',
      // etc.
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

Doing it this way may also work successfully with the getter you defined.

For my work I would rather not trust handling whole objects at once. This is a bit of extra code to write but explicitly defining which properties the expected object should have is valuable to you and others.